# Why am I getting this error on this code involving 2d arrays?

Tags: c

I'm working with 2d arrays here, which I'm not much used to. But I don't suppose I have done anything wrong here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int square(int x)
{
   return x*x;
}

int main()
{
   int t; //number of testcases
   scanf("%d", &t);

   while (t--)
   {
       int n, m, cnt=1;
       scanf("%d %d", &n, &m);
    
       printf("Case %d:\n", cnt);
       cnt++;
    
       int arr[n][2]; //the 2d array with the entire record of the positions of the houses in village
    
       for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
       {
          scanf("%d %d", &arr[i][0], &arr[i][1]);   
       }    
    
       for (int j=0; j<m; j++)
       {
          int h, x, y, total=0;
          scanf("%d %d %d", &h, &x, &y);
          arr[h-1][0]=x;
          arr[h-1][1]=y;
        
          for (int k=0; k<(n-1); k++)
          {
             total+=square((arr[k][0])-arr[k+1][0])); //get error "expected ';' before token )"
             total+=square((arr[k][1])-arr[k+1][1]));
          }
        
          total+=square((arr[n-1][0])-arr[0][0]));
          total+=square((arr[n-1][1])-arr[0][1]));  
        
          printf("%d\n", total);    
       }
   }

   return 0;
}
```

I came up with this as solution to this problem that I will try to briefly describe down below

> Sam distributes newspapers in his village. The village has n houses numbered from 1 to n and they can be identified in the form of a cartesian point (x, y). Every morning Sam starts distributing papers from house 1 and moves on to other houses in order of increasing house number. At the end of his journey, he returns to house 1.
>
> In between his journey, he keeps track of how much it cost to travel that distance. The cost of travelling from one house to another is the square of the euclidean distance between them. To complicate matters, the houses are continually moving from one place to another, changing position. Our job is to calculate the total cost it took to travel the entire journey in relation to the latest positions of the houses.
>
> Now we will be given number of houses, n and number of queries, m. Input will have n lines next where in each line, we will have the corresponding x and y coordinates for that house number. m more lines follow, each line being a query that consists of the number of the house that changed position along with the new coordinates of that particular house.
>
> For each query, we need to print the total cost it will take for Sam then to take one round around the village houses.

(Dev C++) compiler gives me this error message on each of the lines where I implement my square() function:

> **expected ';' before ')' token**

Comment: Can you abbreviate the question?

Comment: Missing / extra parenthesis: `square((arr[k][0])-arr[k+1][0]));` --> `square(arr[k][0]-arr[k+1][0]);`

Comment: @FiddlingBits The actual problem statement rambles much more and is more sprawling and denser than my short description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove an extra parenthesis (`')'`)from these lines

```
total+=square((arr[k][0])-arr[k+1][0])); 
total+=square((arr[k][1])-arr[k+1][1])); 
total+=square((arr[n-1][0])-arr[0][0]));
total+=square((arr[n-1][1])-arr[0][1]));
```

and please check your `while` condition carefully.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int square(int x)
{
   return x*x;
}

int main()
{
   int t; //number of testcases
   scanf("%d", &t);

   while (t--)
   {
       int n, m, cnt=1;
       scanf("%d %d", &n, &m);

       printf("Case %d:\n", cnt);
       cnt++;

       int arr[n][2]; //the 2d array with the entire record of the positions of the houses in village

       for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
       {
          scanf("%d %d", &arr[i][0], &arr[i][1]);   
       }    

       for (int j=0; j<m; j++)
       {
          int h, x, y, total=0;
          scanf("%d %d %d", &h, &x, &y);
          arr[h-1][0]=x;
          arr[h-1][1]=y;

          for (int k=0; k<(n-1); k++)
          {
             total+=square((arr[k][0])-arr[k+1][0]); //removed extra ')'
             total+=square((arr[k][1])-arr[k+1][1]); //removed extra ')'
          }

          total+=square((arr[n-1][0])-arr[0][0]);  //removed extra ')'
          total+=square((arr[n-1][1])-arr[0][1]);  //removed extra ')'

          printf("%d\n", total);    
       }
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be a missing parenthesis or an extra parenthesis? Is that last paren needed?

```
total+=square((arr[k][0])-(arr[k+1][0]));
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler should give you a hint as to where to start looking:

```
main.c:38:52: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘)’ token
              total+=square((arr[k][0])-arr[k+1][0])); //get error "expected ';' before token )"
                                                    ^
main.c:38:52: error: expected statement before ‘)’ token
main.c:39:52: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘)’ token
              total+=square((arr[k][1])-arr[k+1][1]));
                                                    ^
main.c:39:52: error: expected statement before ‘)’ token
main.c:42:51: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘)’ token
           total+=square((arr[n-1][0])-arr[n-1][0]));
                                                   ^
main.c:42:51: error: expected statement before ‘)’ token
main.c:43:51: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘)’ token
           total+=square((arr[n-1][1])-arr[n-1][1]));
                                                   ^
main.c:43:51: error: expected statement before ‘)’ token
```

As you can see, you have several lines with extra `)`s.

Also, a good text editor could perform brace matching for you:

[image: brace matching]

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int square(int x)
{
   return x*x;
}

int main()
{
   int t; //number of testcases
   scanf("%d", &t);

   while (t--)
   {
       int n, m, cnt=1;
       scanf("%d %d", &n, &m);

       printf("Case %d:\n", cnt);
       cnt++;

       int arr[n][2]; //the 2d array with the entire record of the positions of the houses in village

       for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
       {
          scanf("%d %d", &arr[i][0], &arr[i][1]);   
       }    

       for (int j=0; j<m; j++)
       {
          int h, x, y, total=0;
          scanf("%d %d %d", &h, &x, &y);
          arr[h-1][0]=x;
          arr[h-1][1]=y;

          for (int k=0; k<(n-1); k++)
          {
             total+=square((arr[k][0])-arr[k+1][0]); //get error "expected ';' before token )"
             total+=square((arr[k][1])-arr[k+1][1]);
          }

          total+=square((arr[n-1][0])-arr[0][0]);
          total+=square((arr[n-1][1])-arr[0][1]);  

          printf("%d\n", total);    
       }
   }

   return 0;
}
```

it seems that there are extra paranthesises

```
total+=square((arr[k][0])-arr[k+1][0])); //get error "expected ';' before token )"
        total+=square((arr[k][1])-arr[k+1][1]));
}
total+=square((arr[n-1][0])-arr[0][0]));
total+=square((arr[n-1][1])-arr[0][1]));
```